# How do I dynamically connect Teradata and Excel?

Tags: excel, teradata

I want to connect Teradata and Excel in such a manner that will allow me pull only specific data from Teradata. I want to add a drop down list in Excel with the name of my product and I want load data about only that product in Excel.

I tried using the following method Get Data > From Other Sources > From MS Query. I chose my server but got an error 'out of memory'. I am now looking for another method to dynamically link Excel and Teradata.

Comment: You can connect to Teradata using the Teradata drivers by making a "data source" on your PC, but I believe that requires you to point at a table or VIEW. I dont think you can dynamically have a drop down to choose your product, and have that dynamically write a query and have it submit that query dynamically, without getting into VBA and stuff.